# How to make a form validation in InertiaJS

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I am follow this [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpV3BVQJb48&list=PLkZU2rKh1mT8-yRt0Gr5S1ESVRZPB8fKS&index=17) for a `inertiaJS` tutorial. BTW I'm using `laravel 8`

I have this image below from my webpage. I don't know why I don't have a page>errors in picture given. Is there any other way to validate a form other than the link that I provided?.

I commented out the page.error in my HTML because it causes me an error `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined"` because of my Page.Error is an empty object.

[image]

> Update : Code for my controller

[image]

**Script Code**

```
<script>
import Layout from "../../Shared/Layout";
export default {
components: {
   Layout,
},
data() {
return {
  lead: {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    dob: "",
    interested_package: "",
  },
};
},
methods: {
async handleSubmit() {
  let res = await this.$inertia.post("/leads/save", this.lead);
  },
  },
};
</script>
```

**App Service Provider**

```
   public function boot()
{
    //
    Schema::defaultStringLength(255);
    Inertia::share([
        'errors' => function () {
            return Session::get('errors')
                ? Session::get('errors')->getBag('default')->getMessage()
                :  (object)[];
        }
    ]);

    Inertia::share('flash', function () {
        return [
            'message' => Session::get('message'),
            'success' => Session::get('success'),
            'error' => Session::get('error'),
        ];
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you add your controller's code?

Comment: @Andrew I update my Post

Comment: Is this happening with both ```update()``` and ```store()```?

Comment: @Andrew do you mean the validation?. If possible yes

Comment: Can you see anything in the response on the Network tab of the browser's DevTools? What version of ```inertia-vue``` and ```inertia``` are you on (https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/issues/39)?

Also try something like ```let res = await this.$inertia.post("/leads/save", this.lead).then(() => { console.log(this.$page);});``` to see if you get anything in the console.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you I got it now. All I missing this time is `this` word. `this.$page.props.errors.email` this is working now

Comment: @Andrew you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the email error, context needs to be added via the `this` keyword ie. `this.$page.props.errors.email`.

Answer (score 1):

Hey i think you are not sharing error bag in Controller that is why is empty  ,to solve this, go to your **AppServiceProvider**
and add this code.

```
  Inertia::share([
    'errors' => function () {
        return Session::get('errors')
            ? Session::get('errors')->getBag('default')->getMessages()
            : (object) [];
    },
]);
```

Comment: before i post my question. I try that to put in my `appserviceprovider` but still not working or even errors object is still empty

Comment: can you share anything in inertia? also can you dd the session that contains the errors. well the thing is you can do it in another way. but errors should be shared because it is much easier to handle in vue js

Comment: I update my post to see the cut code below the picture.. That's all the code inside my `.vue` and for the inertia